Is there any mechanism to demand order in a joint session of Congress from an unruly speaker?
Is there any mechanism to return Congress to order when a speaker is unruly? Let's say in the middle of a speech, something was said that was maximally distasteful to Congress,

What can the speaker do to demand the statement to be retracted, or modified?
What can a member of Congress do to push the speaker into making that call, or what can they do themselves?

If we need an example for this, let's pretend like a foreign leader was addressing a joint session and said all people that disagree with him are "useful idiots" working for North Korea.

Not my DV, but insulting and unruly are somewhat different concepts, IIRC. Albeit one could subsum them to some word like "unparliamentarian".

I do wonder whom exactly is being attacked here. I guess people read some allusion to some recent event in this, but as I watch a lot less news this summer, it flew right over my head. N.B. there's actually a procedure https://www.everycrsreport.com/reports/R45866.html for calling members to order for unparliamentary language, even if Wikipedia doesn't mention it, for the US.

Generally there are rules regarding unparliamentary language.
However, declaring opponents of Israel's war against Hamas "useful idiots" for Iran clearly doesn't fall under that.
I'm not sure if it's technically possible to object to a non-member's speech on those (unparliamentary speech) grounds, but some member of Congress would generally have to do it right away, and there did not seem to be any takers, in this case.

Rule XVII, clause 4, of the standing rules of the House of Representatives describes a parliamentary mechanism whereby a Member may call another Member to order for the use of disorderly language. Disorderly, or unparliamentary, remarks are a violation of House rules of decorum. This mechanism, which is referred to as “words taken down,” may be invoked during debate on the House floor, in the Committee of the Whole, or in the standing and select committees of the House.
To call a Member to order for allegedly disorderly remarks, a Member would state the following: “I demand that the gentleman’s/gentlewoman’s words be taken down.” This call to order is to occur immediately after the words are spoken. If the demand comes after additional debate or business, the presiding officer may rule that it is untimely. (The presiding officer’s decision on timeliness, however, may be appealed.)
[...] The demand for words to be taken down was invoked 170 times on the House floor or Committee of the Whole between January 1, 1971, and July 24, 2019.

Aside from the fact that I'm not sure if the rules apply to invited foreign leaders, they seem to exclude attacks on vaguely defined groups. E.g. on the contention whether this bit was unparliamentary:

"I do not want my colleague from Indiana to be ashamed whatsoever or to let this element over here who advocates unilateral disarmament to browbeat you into thinking they know more than you do."
The Speaker ruled that the remarks were not directed at a specific Member and, thus, were not unparliamentary. The Speaker cited a precedent set by Speaker Martin on November 24, 1947, in making this ruling.

According to ABC's summary, by those words, Netanyahu "slammed protesters who massed near the U.S. Capitol", whom probably didn't include any Congresspersons in their ranks, making those remarks "not directed at a specific Member", so outside of the remit of US House's unparliamentary speech rules, if they somehow ever applied to Netanyahu's speech.
Aside from that, reports are that some Congresspersons who were opposed to Netanyahu "skipped" his speech. Thus any Congressperson who was more likely to object to anything he said was probably not in attendance to begin with.

Well, that's an absurdly specific definition for "unparliamentary". You could slander the president on the floor of congress and because he's not a member get away with it...

Also, while some congressmen did skip the speech entirely, Rashida Tlaib silently protested, https://www.cbsnews.com/detroit/news/rep-rashida-tlaib-war-criminal-sign-netanyahu-address-congress/
